# CEF Sharp handle the toast that ask for notifications

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I want to be able to get the content of toast notification and how can i communicate with it via c# like this one

[image]

I just start searching and i'm not used to work with cefsharp i found that i can acheive that with **IDisplayHandler** interface 
this is so far my code:

```
   bool IDisplayHandler.OnConsoleMessage(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, ConsoleMessageEventArgs consoleMessageArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(consoleMessageArgs.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(consoleMessageArgs.Source);

        return false;
    }
```

how can i allow notification with c# and get the content of that toast 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `CEF` doesn't support the `notification API`, you can inject some javascript to implement it yourself. See https://github.com/Haltroy/Korot/issues/22 for a discussion on implementing your own.

Comment: so i need to intercept the page and communicate with via noticiationsapi.js then show the resulted notifications is that it ??

Comment: As `CEF` doesn't implement the `notification API` you need to create a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) that implements it yourself, you can use the [CefSharp.PostMessage](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775) javascript function to communicate with your .net application. Two way communication is possible if required. You can inject javascript as required see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: the thing is that i want to be able to process that window even if there's redirection and be able to grant or deny the permission to show notifications on my webBrowser

Comment: Nothing stopping you from injecting your polyfill into every page.

Comment: I have no clue how it need to be done if you can help me at least you would be of great help